# int not being converted to double

Tags: c++

I had `double d = 5;`

When I print d, it prints 5 and not 5.0

What is the general logic here? I thought it should print 5.0 as it should get converted, right?

I mean, when you said `bool b = 23;`, it get's converted to `b = 1;` and prints 1 when you print b.

I want the reason and general logic here please. I can only guess here and assume that bigger (double) can get converted to smaller (int), but not smaller to bigger, is it?

Comment: How do you print it?

Comment: printf("%f", d);  then see what you get.

Comment: Ok, that gives what we expected but I want to use cout. What is happening here?

Comment: Try: std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << d << endl;

Answer (score 3):

It's a formatting issue, the value in memory is still `5.0` floating-point. The default output format for `double` suppresses the decimal part if it is zero.

You can force the decimal part to be displayed by using a fixed format:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << d << std::endl;
```

You might also use the `std::scientific` manipulator:

```
std::cout << std::scientific << d << std::endl;
```

although this format will force the exponent too.

Both `std::fixed` and `std::scientific` are defined in the `iomanip` header.